# Override loadView method of a UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I have a class that is a UIViewController, so in my 'MyViewController.h' I have:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
```

However, in 'MyViewController.m', if I try and override loadView, `-(void)loadView` doesn't autocomplete and since my view isn't showing up, I believe that this is hinting at the problem.

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid but I can't find anything on the matter.

Here's my loadView if it helps:

```
-(void)loadView
{
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

    myInputView = [[MyInputView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth,screenHeight)];
    myInputView.delegate = self; 
    myInputView.style = kGestureInputStyleFading; 
    myInputView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't worry about autocompletion. Simply define your

```
- (void) loadView
```

method and compile your app... If it does not work, please add some code so that we can see what is happening.

In loadView you are expected to initialize the `view` property of your view controller:

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] init...];
```

In your case:

```
-(void)loadView
{
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

myInputView = [[GestureInputView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth,screenHeight)];
myInputView.delegate = self; 
myInputView.style = kGestureInputStyleFading; 
myInputView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; 

self.view = myInputView;
}
```

Comment: Well my view won't show up regardless, I assumed that it might be a hint of what was going wrong. I'll add my loadView if that helps.

Comment: Now it is clear, you are not assigning to `self.view`, which is the view that the view controller manages... see my edit...